# Webhook (or different approach) for getting link data on creation

Tags: branch.io

Is it possible to get the deeplink data from a link that was just created? I would like to persist the link data also in my own database when a user creates a new link.

is this possible? thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: I already created a webhook, which triggers on click. And I fire a `userCompletedAction('click')` right after creating the link. But I guess this webhook would fire every time some user triggers the pre-defined "click" event. when I use a custom event like `userCompletedAction('link-created')`, the webhook doesn't send the link data with it (as stated in the docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: the webhooks system isn't designed to capture link data the way you're describing, but there are a couple of ways you can build this yourself:

1. **Pass a copy of the data to the webhook through a custom event**. If you're only interested in any custom parameters you're setting, you can push those into the link *and* [send them separately](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/user-value-attribution/guide/ios/#appending-custom-metadata) in the custom `link-created` event you're defining.
2. **Retrieve the link data and record it**. If you really want ALL the link data, you can take the link URL that is returned from link generation function, pass that into the [link status API endpoint](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#viewing-state-of-existing-deep-linking-urls), and then do whatever you want with the returned data (either to a webhook through a custom event as above, or directly to your own back end)